Thingsboard - no notification emails
I'm not getting any notification emails. I must be missing the final detail somewhere.
The tenant admin user gets the alarm notifications via the web alright. But nothing via email. Because the logs don't contain any trace of sending emails, I guess I have to tell somewhere the notification must be sent by email too.
What am I missing ? What else can I check ?
THX
What I've checked so far:

The email provider has been set up - sending test emails succeed & arrive in the inbox.
The From field is the email address of the account used to send emails. (some email servers don't like the default dummy address)
The user getting the web notifications has all notification types checked for email in his account notification settings.
The logs don't seem to contain clues about sending emails, at all.
No emails in the spam folder.
No automatic rules in the email client to delete inbound emails.

[update]
Sending explicit email notifications works.
Thingsboard 3.4.6, Debian 12, Docker

Can you share a picture of your alarm rule chain? Is the device assigned to the device profile and then the alarm rule chain is added to the root rule chain properly? Usually, an alarm rule chain(input -> filter script -> msg to meta script -> email notification -> send email) is made it is added to the root rule chain, the device is assigned a device profile and then the device profile is given default rule chain as root rule chain. In email notification and send email you need to set the email smtp setup accordingly I used Brevo for free email sending.
